# Next.js Image isn't displayed inside svg foreignObject in Safari

Tags: image, svg, next.js, safari, foreignobject

I have big svg grid and some cells contains image. I use Next.js Image component for performance and wrap it in foreignObject tag. In Chrome browser this solution works fine, but in Safari I don't see any images.

Code of grid cell is below:

```
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    viewBox={`0 0 ${someValue} ${someValue}`}
>
    <g>
        // ...cells

        <foreignObject
            x={someValue}
            y={someValue}
            width={someValue}
            height={someValue}
        >
            <Image
                quality={50}
                src={`.../api/download/${land.mediaId}`}
                alt="Avatar picture"
                layout="fixed"
                width={someValue}
                height={someValue}
            />
        </foreignObject>

        // ...cells
    </g>
</svg>
```

If I will use standard svg image tag without foreignObject then everything works fine in all browsers, but this solution reduces performance because grid can contain around thousand images.

How I can solve this issue?

Comment: odd, i'd expect performance to be similar. Why aren't you using an html page with a flexbox or grid layout though?

Comment: @RobertLongson For example with next.js Image I can reduce size of images via quality prop.
I can't use grid or flex cause I need to implement a complex shaped map with a lot of cells.

Comment: preprocess the images to reduce their quality then. I don't think quality is a standard html image element property anyway: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, preprocessing the images is possible solution, but I wanted to  make it via next.js built in features. Quality isn't standard prop for Image html, but we are talking about Next.js Image component (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image)